# Problems with Photoshop's onChanging function

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script, adobe-scriptui

I'm trying to change some label text depending on the state of a checkbox for Photoshop Script UI. Only it's not updating at all. No idea why.

Ideally I'd like it to say *"Some text"* when ticked and *"Some other text"* when left unchecked. And change dynamically.

[image: simple UI]

Here's my code

```js
// DIALOG
// ======
var dlg = new Window("dialog");
   dlg.text = "Title"; 
   dlg.preferredSize.width = 180; 
   dlg.preferredSize.height = 100; 
   dlg.orientation = "column"; 
   dlg.alignChildren = ["center","top"]; 
   dlg.spacing = 10; 
   dlg.margins = 16; 

var statictext1 = dlg.add("statictext", undefined, undefined, {name: "statictext1"}); 
   statictext1.text = "Some static text"; 
   statictext1.justify = "center"; 

var checkbox1 = dlg.add("checkbox", undefined, undefined, {name: "checkbox1"}); 
   checkbox1.text = "Some text";
   checkbox1.value = true;
   

// GROUP1
// ======
var group1 = dlg.add("group", undefined, {name: "group1"}); 
    group1.orientation = "row"; 
    group1.alignChildren = ["left","center"]; 
    group1.spacing = 10; 
    group1.margins = 0; 

// add buttons
group1.add ("button", undefined, "OK");
group1.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel");

// Define behavior for when the slider value changes
dlg.checkbox1.onChanging = function() 
{
   var textArr = ["Some text", "Some other text"]
   var val = dlg.checkbox1.value;
   // Update the label text with the current checkbox value.
   dlg.checkbox1.text = textArr[val];
}

var myReturn = dlg.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Checkbox` control fires the `onClick` event and not the `onChanging` event.

The only controls that fire the `onChanging` event are:

- `EditText`
- `Scrollbar`
- `Slider`

Therefore consider changing this part in your script:

```js
// Define behavior for when the slider value changes
dlg.checkbox1.onChanging = function() {
  // ...
}
```

to the following instead:

```js
// Define behavior for when the checkbox value changes
dlg.checkbox1.onClick = function() {
   var textArr = ["Some text", "Some other text"]
   var val = checkbox1.value ? textArr[0] : textArr[1];
   statictext1.text = val;
}
```

#### Explanation

In the body of the preceding function for the `onClick` event, i.e. the part that reads;

```js
var val = checkbox1.value ? textArr[0] : textArr[1];
```

we utilize the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check the `value` property of `checkbox1`. If `checkbox1` is checked *(true)* we assign the string `"Some text"` to the `val` variable, otherwise if `checkbox1` is unchecked *(false)* we assign the string `"Some other text"` to the `val` variable instead.

#### Additional changes:

The following changes also need to be carried out:

1. As `checkbox1`'s initial `value` is set to `true`, i.e. it's checked, you'll need to change line number 13 from this:

   ```js
   statictext1.text = "Some static text";
   ```

   to this:

   ```js
   statictext1.text = "Some text";
   ```
2. Also consider setting the `size` property for `statictext1`. As you can see on line number 15 below the following has been added:

   ```js
   statictext1.size = [180, 20];
   ```

   This will ensure it's width accomodates the `"Some other text"` string.

#### Revised script:

Here is the full revised script:

```js
// DIALOG
// ======
var dlg = new Window("dialog");
    dlg.text = "Title";
    dlg.preferredSize.width = 180;
    dlg.preferredSize.height = 100;
    dlg.orientation = "column";
    dlg.alignChildren = ["center","top"];
    dlg.spacing = 10;
    dlg.margins = 16;

var statictext1 = dlg.add("statictext", undefined, undefined, {name: "statictext1"});
    statictext1.text = "Some text"; // <--- Note: Also change this !
    statictext1.justify = "center";
    statictext1.size = [180, 20];   // <--- Note: Also set the width/height !

var checkbox1 = dlg.add("checkbox", undefined, undefined, {name: "checkbox1"});
    checkbox1.text = "Some text";
    checkbox1.value = true;


// GROUP1
// ======
var group1 = dlg.add("group", undefined, {name: "group1"});
    group1.orientation = "row";
    group1.alignChildren = ["left","center"];
    group1.spacing = 10;
    group1.margins = 0;

// add buttons
group1.add ("button", undefined, "OK");
group1.add ("button", undefined, "Cancel");

// Define behavior for when the checkbox value changes
dlg.checkbox1.onClick = function() {
   var textArr = ["Some text", "Some other text"]
   var val = checkbox1.value ? textArr[0] : textArr[1];
   statictext1.text = val;
}

var myReturn = dlg.show();
```